# Checking wether If each Values of Each Elements from Array Contain in another Array - python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, audio

I'm new to python but I have a project to create a program that using python.
The concept of this program is to categorize the recorded sounds into "class a" and "class b". I tried to use this concept because the results of the recorded sound is so much noise that can not be avoided and not able to being filtered because of noise variation (unpredictable noise).

so first, I have a "sample of sound" that is used as a reference. I change the "sample of sound" into frequency form in the time domain (like spectogram), we may call it "the sound sample".
then I record the sound which is also converted into a frequency form in the time domain (same as "the sample sound" form). we may call "the testing sound".

Both of them ("the sound sample" and "the testing sound") are in the form of multidimensional arrays, which then I want to check whether each value in each elements in "the sample sound" array is contained in "the testing sound".

Now, here's the problems, how to check if a value in some elements of "the sample sound" array is contained in "the testing sound" array ? ... 
here is the code that I used.

```
import wave
import struct
import sys
import numpy as np

def wav_to_floats(wave_file):
w = wave.open('....wav') #>>opening wav file of "the sample sound" 
astr = w.readframes(w.getnframes())

a = struct.unpack("%ih" % (w.getnframes()* w.getnchannels()), astr)
a = [float(val) for val in a]

return a

the_sample_sound =  np.array(wav_to_floats(sys.argv[0]))

def wav_to_floats_2 (wav_file):
v = wave.open('....wav') #opening wav file of "the testing sound"
astu = v.readframes(v.getnframes())

b = struct.unpack("%ih" % (v.getnframes()* v.getnchannels()), astu)
b = [float(val) for val in b]

return b

the_testing_sound = np.array(wav_to_floats_2(sys.argv[0]))

time = 30 #duration time of sound (both "the sample sound" and "the testing sound") is 30 second

c = np.array_split(the_sample_sound, time)

for i in range (time) :
d = np.abs(np.fft.fft(c[i]))

e = np.array_split(the_testing_sound, time)

for j in range (time) :
f = np.abs(np.fft.fft(e[i]))

# i tried to use this block code to check value from the sample sound to the testing sound but it could not work

h = 0 

for i in (d) :
    for j in (e) :
        for u in (j) :
            if u in (i) :
                h += 1
            else :
                h += 0

print (h) #>> to sum how many times value in sample sound is contained in the testing sound
```

additional info I use python 3x and sorry for bad english ..

Comment: Have you tried Numpy's `isin` function? see here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html

Comment: ok .. thx .. let me try it ..
is it correct the code becoming this way...
......
for u in (d) :
    for v in (f) :
       h = np.isin(v, u)
.....

Comment: What's the shape of `d` and `f`?

Comment: array with several sub array : i.e. [(a,b,c) ; (d,e,f)].. kind of multidimensional array @Blademaster